# Running istanbul, coveralls, and ts-node to create typescript test coverage?

Tags: javascript, typescript, istanbul, coveralls, ts-node

I have [a project](https://github.com/fsngx/ease) with two typescript files:
- `src/index.ts`
- `src/index.spec.ts`

I can run the mocha unit tests without first compiling the typescript to commonjs format like this:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts
```

I'd also like to run istantbul and I tried this:

```
istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts - - -R spec
```

I got that snippet from [this article](https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724) (It's tweaked to support `ts-node`.

When `istanbul cover` is ran like that the result is:

```
    > @fsngx/ease@1.0.0 cover /home/ole/fsngx/ease
    > istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts - - -R spec

    Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: ts-node/register
    Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: -
```

Is it possible to run `istanbul cover` using `ts-node` or do we need to run that command on compiled typescript?

Comment: To run istanbul - you need to add a dedicated script to package.json. E.g.:   `"coverage": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha"`, also - you seem to be missing `"require": [ "ts-node/register" ]` and `include: ["./YOUR_ACTUAL_PATH/**/*.spec.ts"]`. Consider checking the official tutorial https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/typescript/

Comment: see my config for mocha/nyc (i do not claim its the most eficient, though, but it works and generates coverage) - https://github.com/c69/hs-sim/blob/master/package.json and https://github.com/c69/hs-sim/blob/master/test/mocha.opts

Comment: @c69 thanks - I did attempt to implement the approach used in https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/typescript/ and updated the repository correspondingly.  It does not look like my package.json script is picking up mocha.opts.  Added another more detailed post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374421/adding-support-for-istanbul-test-coverage-for-mocha-unit-tests-written-in-typesc